# How to add custom view in BlurDialogFragment

Tags: android, dialog, android-alertdialog

I need blur background in behind dialog screen. I found good solution using this link https://github.com/tvbarthel/BlurDialogFragment but in this library not specify how to integrate custom view. here in code showing that we need to create AlertDialog in OnCreateDialog method but can we use setcontentview() in onCreateDialog method.

```
 @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        View view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_fragment, null);
        TextView label = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView));
        label.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
        Linkify.addLinks(label, Linkify.WEB_URLS);
        builder.setView(view);
        return builder.create();
    }
```

Comment: http://tvbarthel.fr/blur-dialog-fragment.html

Answer (score 1):

You can create a class that extends BlurDialogFragment and in the onCreateView method you can inflate your custom layout.
See the example below:

```
public class CustomDialogFragment extends BlurDialogFragment {


@Override
protected boolean isActionBarBlurred() {
    // Enable or disable the blur effect on the action bar.
    // Disabled by default.
    return true;
}

@Override
protected int getBlurRadius() {
    // Allow to customize the blur radius factor.
    return 7;
}

@Override
protected boolean isDimmingEnable() {
    // Enable or disable the dimming effect.
    // Disabled by default.
    return false;
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_fragment_layout, container, false);


    return v;
}
```

To show the dialog from your Activity:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
CustomDialogFragment cdf = new CustomDialogFragment();
cdf.show(fragmentManager,"yourTag");
```